# Regex to replace all comma except enclosed in double quotes java

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace all  commas except in double quotes in java using regex.I am excepting output as `\"Lee Rounded Neck, Printed\"#410.00#300.00#\"Red Blue\"#lee"`

```
String line="\"Lee Rounded Neck, Printed\" 410.00 300.00,\"Red Blue\",lee";
    String repl = line.replaceAll("(?!\")\\,", "#");
    System.out.println("Replaced => " + repl);
```

But i am getting   `"Lee Rounded Neck# Printed" 410.00 300.00#"Red Blue"#lee`

Please someone Help me in this regards

Comment: Here's how it would look in Perl: `s/((?:[^",]|"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*")*),/$1#/g`.  This also allows `"` to be escaped by a backslash inside a `"`-quoted string.  `$1` refers to the first parenthesised expression; I expect there's a way to express this in Java.

Answer (score 2):

Try with,

```
line.replaceAll(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", "#");
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Without regex:

```
String line="\"Lee Rounded Neck, Printed\" 410.00 300.00,\"Red Blue\",lee";
System.out.println(line);

char[] line2 = line.toCharArray();
boolean insideQuotes = false;
for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); ++i) {
  if (line.charAt(i) == '\"')
    insideQuotes = !insideQuotes;
  else if (line.charAt(i) == ',' && !insideQuotes)
    line2[i] = '#';
}
line = String.valueOf(line2);
System.out.println(line);
```

Output:

```
"Lee Rounded Neck, Printed" 410.00 300.00,"Red Blue",lee
"Lee Rounded Neck, Printed" 410.00 300.00#"Red Blue"#lee
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/iIBzkA)